# How should I store global information such as a phone number so that it is editable through the CMS?

Tags: theme-development, customization, globals

Right now I have a p element in header.php containing the address and phone number my client wishes to use for contact info. How can I set this up so that it is editable through the WP admin area so that my client can easily change this in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store it in your theme options. Read the series of articles called [The Complete Guide To The WordPress Settings API](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-1/). Spare no effort to read it, especially 4th article about [Theme Options](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-4-on-theme-options/).

Comment: Great! That's what I was doing. Thanks for the link to the article series too.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a plugin exactly for this case: [Public Contact Data](https://github.com/toscho/Public-Contact-Data). Last update just yesterday. :)

It can be extended easily by a filter `'pcd_fields'`, and the data are accessible by `do_action()` or custom shortcodes. It is translatable (of course), and a German translation is already included.

Before that I have put these things into themes too. But managing that was awkward, especially updates for multiple themes using this code.

*Screenshot: Background shows the output in a theme, foreground the translated option fields.*

[image]

Comment: Awesome! And it even supports German, great. I have no experience with plugin development yet, so this is a noob question but does it store the data in the wp_options table or what?

Comment: Yes, the data ist stored as a serialized array in the option `'public_contact_data'`. In other words: It will survive a theme switch.